# How to solve permission errors when deploying flask app on apache using wsgi?

Tags: python, linux, apache, flask, apache2

I am having an issue deploying a flask app on apache2 using wsgi. Apache2 restarts as if it is running fine, but when I try to access it with a browser I get a "403 Forbidden" error. Here is my code.

webroombooker.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

sys.path.insert(0,"/home/pi/Website/webroombooker.py")

from webroombooker import app as application
```

Here is my directory tree of the directory Flask application and wsgi file are in.

```
/home/pi/Website
├── hellotest.py
├── hellotest.pyc
├── index.html.en
├── index.html.en~orig.html
├── main.html
├── PoweredByMacOSX.gif
├── PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif
├── templates
│       ├── profile.html
│       ├── registration2.html
│       ├── registration.html
│       ├── seleniumtemplate2.html
│       └── seleniumtemplatetime.html
├── Test
├── webroombooker.py
├── webroombooker.pyc
└── webroombooker.wsgi
```

And here is the apache virtual host file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName localhost

            WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/Website/webroombooker.wsgi

            <Directory /home/pi/Website/webroombooker.py/>
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are the relevant error log lines
Actually it is showing an error now.

```
[Thu Nov 17 14:07:39.939432 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 15949:tid          1972368432] [client ::1:55490] AH01630: client denied by server     configuration: /home/pi/Website/webroombooker.wsgi
[Thu Nov 17 14:07:40.260731 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 15949:tid 1963979824] [client ::1:55490] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/Website/webroombooker.wsgi, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu Nov 17 14:07:43.506135 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 15949:tid 1955591216] [client ::1:55490] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/Website/webroombooker.wsgi
[Thu Nov 17 14:07:43.702542 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 15949:tid 1947202608] [client ::1:55490] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/Website/webroombooker.wsgi, referer: http://localhost/
```

I'm pretty new to this so I really appreciate it. Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant lines of the apache log files?

Comment: For some reason the apache log is showing no errors when I request the site.

Comment: Actually it is showing an error now. I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a result of your unix permissions on some file that apache is accessing.  Apache runs as the user `www-data`, where as the files are probably owned by your user.  Try running `sudo chmod a+w <filename>` for the relevant files, which would probably be your wsgi files

Comment: Tried that, all permissions are set correctly I believe. View change and execute privileges are set to Anyone. On every file in Website directory.

Comment: Can you include /home/pi/Website/webroombooker.wsgi in your question? The error seems to be saying that something inside there is denying the client access to whatever resource is being requested.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I believe that is what is in the first code block in the question. I just renamed it. My Bad.

Comment: Great! Mind upvoting and marking my answer as correct if it helped? :)

Comment: No I meant I just renamed it in the question, it was called webroombooker.wsgi on my machine. I would upvote you because you are being very helpful but unfortunately I don't have access to that privilege yet. Any idea what is causing this permission error?

Comment: Oh I see.  I'm sorry, I'm not sure what could be causing this unfortunately

Comment: Does the wsgi file look right to you? This if my first time doing it. The default apache website is still deploying when i type in my Pi's IP instead of localhost.

Comment: To address your last comment, I believe you'd have to specify your IP as another ServerName in your apache config file, or else it will only use those rules when the host being requested is localhost.  Unfortunately I have no experience with Apache, only nginx.  If you're interested in trying nginx, I actually just put a template and tutorial together yesterday for deploying a flask app with nginx! https://github.com/chrisshroba/flask-wsgi-nginx-template  Also, I don't think this is the problem since you're getting a 403 and not a 500, but are you actually running uwsgi for apache to talk to?

Comment: I installed the wsgi apache framework. How can I check?

Comment: Wait I think I found a problem at the end of my flask app it says app.run(0.0.0.0) the same location of the apache default page. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey any chance you can upvote my question someone just downvoted it and I don't know why.

Comment: I think the way wsgi works is that uwsgi should always be running, and the web server (apache/nginx) gets requests and hands them off to uwsgi over a unix socket. Then uwsgi converts taht request into a python object, and passes it on to your program.  you shouldn't be calling app.run in your program, because thats just the dev server.  If you do call it, put it in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block so it doesnt run when uwsgi runs your thing. This tutorial might be helpful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean cache:

```py
find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
```